# Navigating between invisible views programmatically iOS 13

Tags: swift, xcode, ios13

I have several tabs. When I open settings view in current tab, I want the settings views in another tabs to be opened too. When close I want to get the same behaviour.
And I did it. When I open settings I use segue approach:

```
navControllers.forEach { navController in navController.topViewController!.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSettings", sender: nil) }
```

When I close I use:

```
navControllers.forEach { navController in navController.popViewController(animated: false) }
```

Everything was perfect, until recent updates of Xcode and swift version.
After this I started to get runtime warning message in console regarding the "close code":

> UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents
>   without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its
>   superviews has not been added to a window)

After inspecting view hierarchy in debugger I found out that it's actually yelling on settings table view! The view "without being in the view hierarchy" appeared to be the view which even doesn't exist anymore because of being closed!
It really looks like a system bug. But how can I bypass it? Very frustrating.

Comment: Use unwind segue instead.

Comment: Yes, that's a reasonable advise, thank you. I've tried that also. In that case I've got another type of warning: "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions". But I found a solution already. I'll post it in a minute.

Comment: Btw how do u keep a reference for all navigations ? you don't need to do that.

Comment: I have four tabs. Every tab has a navigation controller as a root controller. As for keeping reference: navControllers = tabBarController!.viewControllers as! [UINavigationController]. After this I also have to delete navigation controller of a current tab, before performing navControllers.forEach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One line solution.
Before `navController.popViewController(animated: false)`

```
settingsTableViewController.tableView.removeFromSuperview()
```

It costs me four days of struggling :)

Comment: Does it get added back in automagically when once again showing SettingsTableViewController?

Comment: When once again showing SettingsTableViewController, actually it's not the old one to be showed (that one was deleted (destroyed) when navController.popViewController). The completely new instance of SettingsTableViewController will be created and showed. So yes, there will not be any problem with tableView and it's superview.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note, I also found that if you call `DispatchQueue.main.async`, and paste your code in there, it will also work, without having to remove the element from the superview.

ex:

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  // Set up tableView
  self.tableViewLeadingConstraint.constant = -225
  self.tableViewTrailingConstraint.constant = -450
  self.tableViewOut.alpha = 1
  self.tableViewOut.isOpaque = true
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Found the solution towards the end of this Apple forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/120790

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was when hiding navigation bar in viewDidDisappear. Removing UITableView from superView just before - removed the warning.

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        // FIXED TABLEVIEW LAYOUT WARNING ON CLOSING !!!
        // FIXED TABLEVIEW LAYOUT WARNING ON CLOSING !!!
        // FIXED TABLEVIEW LAYOUT WARNING ON CLOSING !!!
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/58197432/44964
        self.aboutTableView?.removeFromSuperview()
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }
```

Comment: In xcode if you add "// MARK: FIXED TABLEVIEW LAYOUT WARNING ON CLOSING!!!" It will highlight bright white in the code and also show up in the thumbnail navigator on the right of the edit window if you have that enabled :-) Might spare you a couple of repeated comments.

Comment: I also use "// TODO: ..." a lot